# Karma afterAll-Error on every second build

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

we tried to let the building pipeline run unit test for angular, which worked fine in the first try. Second try failed with the error:

```
✓ ‌should create‌
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR‌
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
  }
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 30 of 30 ERROR (0 secs / 1.145 secs)
HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
  }
```

Every test was successful but at the afterAll this error occured. I was wondering why and so i ran the pipeline again. With Success. But Build after that again failes with the same issue. Since then every second build is failing.

On my way through google I found some problems which seemed to be similuar. One guy said the problem could occur because the test will be ran in random order. So i disabled the random order which you can see in the karma.conf.js below.

Another guy said he was able to find the error by using the 'karma-spec-reporter', so I added it also to the conf.

My conf now looks like this:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/hts'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'spec'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Here is a log of a failing test:

```
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6728528Z > ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6728557Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6728872Z [32m28 05 2019 11:44:41.520:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6729152Z [32m28 05 2019 11:44:41.526:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6729727Z [32m28 05 2019 11:44:41.544:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6730283Z [32m28 05 2019 11:45:06.962:INFO [HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket D5MowUVbw8jTkj6eAAAA with id 99860190
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6734720Z HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735145Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.011 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735180Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735250Z   AppComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735485Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create the app
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735748Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.012 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6735941Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736003Z   AuthPageComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736242Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736502Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.013 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736531Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736588Z   LoggedOutComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6736781Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737037Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.013 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737078Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737132Z   LoginComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737329Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737764Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.045 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737790Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6737852Z   AuthenticationInterceptorService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738046Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738294Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.055 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738332Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738386Z   AuthenticationService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738578Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738824Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 7 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.09 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738851Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6738907Z   AuthGuard
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6739091Z     [32m✓ [39mshould ...
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6739977Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 8 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.09 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6740032Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6740093Z   HomeComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6740294Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6740550Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 9 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.092 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6740781Z     [32m✓ [39mshould add environment into tile
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741042Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 10 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.13 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741080Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741116Z   ConfigService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741333Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741594Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 11 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.164 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741621Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741657Z   ExportService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6741869Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6742531Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.189 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6742595Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6742635Z   HtsService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6742889Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6743330Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 13 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.21 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6743358Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6743412Z   IngredientsService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6764640Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765022Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 14 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.229 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765074Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765145Z   UserService
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765352Z     [32m✓ [39mshould be created
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765595Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 15 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.23 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765622Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765680Z   ChartsComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6765864Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766105Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 16 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.232 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766361Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766422Z   DataTabsComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766643Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766887Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 17 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.232 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766914Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6766966Z   FilterPanelComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6767158Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6767403Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 18 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.233 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6767533Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6767590Z   GeneralFilterComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6767794Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6768034Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 19 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.233 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6768665Z     [32m✓ [39mshould add a new filter when addFilter is called
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6768908Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 20 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.234 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769128Z     [32m✓ [39mshould delete filter when call deleteFilterRow
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769368Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 21 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.239 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769415Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769449Z   IngredientFilterComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769632Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6769868Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 22 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.24 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770111Z     [32m✓ [39mshould add a new filter when addFilter is called
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770350Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 23 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.242 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770555Z     [32m✓ [39mshould delete filter when call deleteFilterRow
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770812Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 24 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.244 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770838Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6770871Z   PropertyFilterComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6771062Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6771322Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 25 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.244 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6771530Z     [32m✓ [39mshould add a new filter when addFilter is called
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6771768Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 26 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.244 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6771994Z     [32m✓ [39mshould delete filter when call deleteFilterRow
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772247Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 27 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.244 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772274Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772306Z   StandardRow
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772518Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create an instance
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772762Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 28 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.244 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772787Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6772820Z   TableComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773018Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773271Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 29 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.247 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773298Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773331Z   IngredientsListComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773528Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773767Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 30 of 30 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.145 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773792Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6773825Z   UserComponent
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774030Z     [32m✓ [39mshould create
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774231Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774270Z   {
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774308Z     "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774365Z     "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774399Z   }
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774436Z HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 30 of 30 ERROR (0 secs / 1.145 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774490Z HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6774616Z   {
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775111Z     "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775166Z     "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775220Z   }
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775508Z [31mHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR[39m
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775550Z   {
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775606Z     "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown",
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775765Z     "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught [object Object] thrown"
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6775799Z   }
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6776075Z [1A[2KHeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 30 of 30 ERROR (1.242 secs / 1.145 secs)
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6776125Z 
2019-05-28T11:45:17.6776370Z HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 30 of 30[31m ERROR[39m (1.242 secs / 1.145 secs)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are having the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Bob sorry for being that late. The Problem was that we were calling real services with real backends. We mocked the services in the components we were using them, but we didn't provided the mocked services in the components which are holding the components which are using the services :D